# Change focus on press Up/Down button

Tags: javascript, html

everyone!

I've div tag, for instance

```
<style>
  #DistrictStyle li:hover { background-color: rgb(129,171,242);}
</style>
<div id="DistrictList" style=  "display: none;
                                      z-index: 500;
                                      list-style-type: none;
                                      border: 1px solid rgb(129,171,242);
                                      background-color: white;
                                      max-height:150px;
                                      overflow-y:scroll; position:absolute;
                                      left: 208px; top: 135px; "><ul id="DistrictStyle"></ul></div>
```

So, now on mouse click of record of this list I fill several fields. And I need to navigate by Up/Down button thru list.

```
<li onclick='fill_distr(" + x + ");'>" + "</li>";
```

How can I achieve this? Can I only use pure JS or ought to use jQuery? I guess I should catch events of mouse focus and press "enter".
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change focus of what? How does it get focused? If you are building a menu you should have anchors inside of the li elements.

Comment: What do you mean by "navigate up/down?"  Are you talking about focusing elements or displaying them?  Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can go both ways. JQuery allows easy event handling though. Check out the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) for all functions.

Note: Not sure if you use HTML5, but if it's the case you shouldn't use style attributes in your html elements.. Just saying :)

Edit: Just to point you in the right direction. [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) should do for you :)